# How can I detect if a type has an operator << overload?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a generic printing template, so a more specific wording of the question would be: how can I determine if some `operator<<` method is overloaded for a type?

Comment: The compiler will throw an error when an overload isn't defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using boost.TypeTraits, specifically with [has_left_shift](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_left_shift.html). An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/type_traits.hpp"

struct foo
{
    int i;
};

struct bar
{
    int j;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& f)
{
    return os << f.i;
}

int main()
{
    // Prints out 1 == true
    std::cout << boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream&, foo&, std::ostream&>::value << '\n';
    // Prints out 0 == false
    std::cout << boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream&, bar&, std::ostream&>::value << '\n';
}
```

Watch out for the known issues, however, which are listed down the bottom of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

SFINAE can help you to check if a certain method has been provided.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Generic {};
struct Printable{};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Printable& t) {
    return o;
}

// SFINAE test
typedef char one;
typedef struct { char a[2]; } two;

template <typename T> static one printable_test(std::ostream&o, decltype (o << T{}, 0) ) ;
template <typename T> static two printable_test(...);

template <typename T> bool printable_with(std::ostream& o) { 
    return sizeof(printable_test<T>(o, 0)) == sizeof(one);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << printable_with<Generic>(std::cout) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << printable_with<Printable>(std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/KBDOK74553)

Some explanations.

There're 2 overloaded function templates `printable_test`, the overload resolution result of invoking of them in `printable_with()` will tell the result.

The 1st version takes `decltype (o << T{}, 0)` as its 2nd parameter, which is valid only when `o << T{}` is valid, i.e. `operator<<` on `T` is provided, and then `decltype` will take `0` (the last expression of comma expression) as its type, so this version will match the invoking best.

Otherwise, i.e. `operator<<` on `T` is not provided, the 2nd version will be adopted.

Comment: Careful: SFINAE can only detect whether a certain method has been *declared*. If a declaration is available, then SFINAE cannot detect whether it will actually work. There are common cases of `operator<<` template definitions that break at instantiation time.